# Magic bitboards not speeding up chess engine

Tags: c++, chess

I'm new to writing chess engines but just recently finished my first program. It ran slowly however so I switched over to bitboards, and now to magic bitboards. I used the chess programming wiki a lot.

I'm now trying a test position and a perft function to see how many nodes per second the program can calculate (including bulk-counting). Right now my perft function is set to calculate only pseudo legal moves and I have set the make_move function to not switch the turn. Therefore I can analyze the position R7/8/8/8/8/8/8/8 w - - with perft.

My problem however is that without magic bitboards, I get 6.22 million nodes per second, and with I only get 6.29. It seems that my magic bitboards are not working properly. It feels intuitively that the speed up of magic bitboards should be much greater. Also, 95% of the computing time is spent in my pseudo legal move generator.

As I mentioned, I'm new to chess engines, and especially magic bitboards. I didn't know how to finish the look up table properly and right now I have a table (for rooks) of 64*8192 entries. I initialize this table at the start of the program by calculating all different combinations of blockers for each square. Then my index is given by (occ >> (64-13))+8192 * square, to not get overlaps in the table entries. (From https://www.chessprogramming.org/Magic_Bitboards).

Is the reason for my slow magic bitboards my gigantic table size? Is there another way to do this more effectively?

It is totally possible that the reason the speed up is so small is because the time is not spend generating moves, but rather iterating over the bits in the different bitboards. Is there a way to speed up this process? It seems (with some googling) that my functions

```cpp
int ls1b(u64 bitboard) {
    if (bitboard) {
        return count((bitboard & -bitboard) - 1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

and

```cpp
int count(u64 bitboard) {
    int count = 0;
    while(bitboard) {
        count++;
        bitboard &= bitboard - 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

are as fast as they can be. How does stockfish (or other c++ engines) do this iterating?

Comment: You need a good profiler - it's no use trying to just guess why your program is slow.

Comment: Can you recommend any good profilers for c++ code @500-InternalServerError?

Comment: That would be off-topic here - besides I don't know your platform.

Comment: I'm on windows, but I also have a linux computer if that would help me. Should I post a new question then @500-InternalServerError?

Comment: Seeking recommendations are generally off-topic on SO, since there can be no correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment on the rest of your program since I cannot see it, but as for your bit functions, they can be improved, see:

https://www.chessprogramming.org/BitScan#Trailing_Zero_Count
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight

```
int lsb(uint64_t bb) {
   static const int lookup67[67+1] = {
      64,  0,  1, 39,  2, 15, 40, 23,
       3, 12, 16, 59, 41, 19, 24, 54,
       4, -1, 13, 10, 17, 62, 60, 28,
      42, 30, 20, 51, 25, 44, 55, 47,
       5, 32, -1, 38, 14, 22, 11, 58,
      18, 53, 63,  9, 61, 27, 29, 50,
      43, 46, 31, 37, 21, 57, 52,  8,
      26, 49, 45, 36, 56,  7, 48, 35,
       6, 34, 33, -1 };
   return lookup67[(bb & -bb) % 67];
}

const uint64_t m1  = 0x5555555555555555; //binary: 0101...
const uint64_t m2  = 0x3333333333333333; //binary: 00110011..
const uint64_t m4  = 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0f; //binary:  4 zeros,  4 ones ...
const uint64_t h01 = 0x0101010101010101; //the sum of 256 to the power of 0,1,2,3...

int count(uint64_t x)
{
    x -= (x >> 1) & m1;             //put count of each 2 bits into those 2 bits
    x = (x & m2) + ((x >> 2) & m2); //put count of each 4 bits into those 4 bits 
    x = (x + (x >> 4)) & m4;        //put count of each 8 bits into those 8 bits 
    return (x * h01) >> 56;  //returns left 8 bits of x + (x<<8) + (x<<16) + (x<<24) + ... 
}
```